# Conda not able to call its python version

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, anaconda, conda

I am getting an issue in the conda environment, the conda environment is not able to call its python version. I installed a different version of python in my conda environment but it is still calling the base python version of Ubuntu 22.04.

I tried the following.

```
conda create -n bioinfo_env krakenuniq python=2.7.18

conda activate bioinfo_env

python --version

$ python 3.10.10
```

However, it should show python 2.7.18

Comment: There are many possible reasons for this. One could be that you have python as an alias and not just a path. One could be that this particular conda environment that you are creating does not provide a python executable. Have you verified that you can run the conda python by calling it directly?

Comment: It is not only in this created environment but conda is not able to call the python version from any other environment. It always calls the base Python version 3.10.10 but there are different python in different environments.

Comment: What terminal do you use (terminal, not shell)? How is Conda on PATH to begin with? E.g., what code is in your shell initialization file? Please add responses as edit to question, not as a comment.

Comment: Can you run `type python` and report the output? Maybe you have created a python alias at some point?